# Cleaner Cast Syntax

Tags: c#

Is there any other way to do this without all the extra outside parens here?

```
((ScheduledTask)(scheduledTasks[intCount])).TaskIntervalType
```

Comment: You can drop the parentheses surrounding `scheduledTasks[intCount]` but that's as far as you can go without changing to `as` casting or using local variables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhat better:

```
(scheduledTasks[intCount] as ScheduledTask).TaskIntervalType
```

Note that the behavior would be somewhat different: The as cast will not throw an exception when not successful, but return `null` - so you would get a `NullReferenceException` (when trying to access the property on a `null` reference) instead of a cast exception.

Comment: Not equivalent statement.

Comment: If you are sure that that the value is `ScheduledTask` and that it is not null then using `((ScheduledTask)(scheduledTasks[intCount]))` is better form performance than using `as` keyword

Comment: Indeed, not equivalent. Not only does it throw a `NullReferenceException` instead of an `InvalidCastException` (thus making it harder to debug what went wrong), the `as` operator also doesn't use custom conversions defined by classes which the original does.

Comment: @Sven It does not throw `NullReferenceException`. It simply returns `null`.

Comment: The `as` operator itself doesn't throw a `NullReferenceException`, but his code does because it tries to use the result without checking for `null`.

Comment: I don't like this code. `as` is for when you're not sure about if what you're casting is of the type you cast to. But in your code it will only work correctly if the cast always succeeds.

Comment: You could do a `ScheduledTask.TryParse ()` so you get the output as well as a boolean if you can Parse or not

Answer (score 4):

```
var task = (ScheduledTask)scheduledTasks[intCount];
var interval = task.TaskIntervalType;
```

You could use the `as` keyword instead:

```
var task = scheduledTasks[intCount] as ScheduledTask;
var interval = task.TaskIntervalType;
```

but it would change the behaviour of the cast. For one, as noted, it will return `null` instead of throwing an exception for a failed conversion. For another, it will not perform any custom conversions between types that you might have.

Although with that said, using `as` is probably better than casting because it behaves in a more consistent and reliable way than a cast.

And with all *that* said, perhaps the right approach would be to change your array to be strongly typed or expose the TaskIntervalType as a property on an interface or base class? That way casting would not be needed at all.

For example,

```
public interface ITask
{
    IntervalType TaskIntervalType { get; }
}

public ScheduledTask : ITask
{}

public MyStuff()
{
    List<ITask> scheduledTasks = new List<ITask>();
    // populate the list, etc...

    /// ... and back to your example:
    var type = scheduledTasks[intCount].TaskIntervalType;
}
```

Comment: If I was a var advocate this would rock.  Unfortunately my preference is that I don't like the var keyword.  I don't want to get into that debate either but thanks for your post...this is a useful reply to people who are var advocates or willing to embrace var :).

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Nothing I wrote requires you to use `var`. Feel free to replace it with explicit types. :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be safer (not sure about the variable names and types):

```
    ScheduledTask Task =  scheduledTasks[intCount] as ScheduledTask;

    IntervalType TaskType;

    if (Task != null)
    {
        TaskType = Task.TaskIntervalType;
    }
```